# prevent Request Method:OPTIONS in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm sending an ajax request to my server (GET or POST) and the request done successfully but problem is before my main request sencha sends a request method called OPTIONS that is not my intention and because of that it fails . how i can disable this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved! in phonegap this will not be a problom because browser is sender of request actually not sencha ! and if you want to disable it in your chrome browser simply run it with these options :

> ```
> `chromium-browser --args --disable-web-security`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ext.Ajax.request, just add parameter:

```
useDefaultXhrHeader : false
```

If you are using Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, edit /sdk/src/data/Connection.js, set useDefaultXhrHeader to false.

If not, GET and POST method request will contain X-Requested-With header. I think this header is the reason why OPTIONS method request is sent.